# change keyboard keys in english keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout

I am using an english ( US ) keyboard. The position for @ on the keyboard is shift 2, but I ve to do it with Alt Q and I want to correct this. The # should be on shift 3 but is positioned on the key beyond the tab key. I d like to correct this in the xmodmap, but I dont know to do it. can anybobody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The way to type # is already <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> with the English (US) keyboard layout.

To fix @ the way you want, I would suggest that you edit the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` file directly. An example:

```
--- us.orig
+++ us
@@ -17,7 +17,7 @@
     key <AE11> {   [     minus,    underscore  ]   };
     key <AE12> {   [     equal,    plus        ]   };
 
-    key <AD01> {   [     q,    Q       ]   };
+    key <AD01> {   [     q,    Q, at       ]   };
     key <AD02> {   [     w,    W       ]   };
     key <AD03> {   [     e,    E       ]   };
     key <AD04> {   [     r,    R       ]   };
@@ -54,6 +54,8 @@
     key <AB10> {   [     slash,    question    ]   };
 
     key <BKSL> {   [ backslash,         bar    ]   };
+
+    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
 };
 
 partial alphanumeric_keys
```

With those changes (and after a relogin) you can do:

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> -> @